# LG V30 won't show up in connected devices in NativeScript SideKick

Tags: android, nativescript

When connected via USB, my LG V30 won't show up in NativeScript SideKick's Devices panel, nor will running `tns devices` list the phone.

I have installed the universal USB drivers for LG devices from: http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers

and I am able to successfully view the files on the phone via Windows Explorer and also via LG Bridge.

I am able to successfully run the project on an emulator via `tns run android --emulator`

`tns doctor` reports a clean bill of health and my project will build successfully. What else can I do to get SideKick to recognize my device via USB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the first item to try is `adb devices` from your computer.  I assume it isn't showing here and this is why it isn't working anywhere as this is the communication channel for development.

Now to make this work this is typically because you do not have USB debugging turned on.  Which is in Developer Options.

If you already have **Developer Options** in your settings, then you can skip the next step.

To enable **Developer Options** you go to your **Settings**, then **About** or **About Phone/Device**, then **Software information**.   Once there you tap the **Build Number** seven times.    This will then create a new menu option typically in your **Settings** called **Developer Options**

To enable USB Debugging, go to your **Settings** then click **Developer Options** then find "USB debugging" and turn it on.    At that point you might need to unplug and replug in your device and then adb devices` should show it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm brand-new to native development as I'm sure you could tell :)

Comment: Not a problem, everyone starts somewhere!

Comment: I also had to change the "USB option" to "Transfer images" to get it to show up as a device in ADB.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with LG V30 changing USB type to 'MIDI' solved issue - it was after that visible in adb as an authorized device and I was able to build my app.